# Inserting many object into only one canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have got a problem with inserting many dots (for example 10000) into only one canvas. They must appear one by one on the screen(canvas) and stay them as long as function Dots() is running. Position (x,y) of every dot is randomize:

```
function Dots() {
  let coordinates = new Array();
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    /* Double using because x nad y value must be calculate separately! */
    let x = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
    let y = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
    coordinates.push(x,y);
  }
  return coordinates;
}
```

I thought about moving the array inside canvas, but maybe there is a better way.

```
function draw() {
  /* Dimensions of canvas are in the HTML id */
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  Dots();

  // taking x and y from the array
  for (let j=0; j<coordinates.length/2; j++) {
  let Y = 150 - coordinates[2*j+1]; // y axis direction change

  // dots as a 1px rectangle
  ctx.fillRect(coordinates[2*j],Y,1,1);
  }
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing away the result of your *almost* pure function `Dots` (aside from the Math.random call). Instead assign it to a local variable.

```
const coordinates = Dots();
```

When defining variables inside functions they are local to that function. That means that the `coordinates` variable inside `Dots` won't be visible from `draw`. As an example:

```
let foo = 42;
(() => { let foo = 56; })();
console.log(foo); // Logs 42
```

Also the call to `ctx.moveTo` is superfluous and used only for drawing paths. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes) reference.

Since the call to `Dots` finishes instantaneously you could store the result and then animate by calling draw multiple times. See [this Pen](https://codepen.io/axelf4/pen/oMzYJV) for an example.

Comment: Then name of the const will be the same as returned array - "coordinates"

Comment: That won't matter since they are in different scopes. See my updated answer.

Comment: I understand but giving the same name for different things (variable and array) could make mistake in the later time (when the code will be much bigger). But OK. What about main subject?

Comment: OK, it works. I also try to put recently number of dots into HTML <div>, but my code doesn't work. let progress = (i/10000)*100; document.getElementById('progress').textContent = `${progress}`;

Comment: Did ya stick that in the Dots function? As I said it returns immediately. I have updated the pen to use a generator function, which I think maps closer to what you want to achieve.

Comment: OK, whole code working, but what does * symbol mean in the function* ?

Comment: Refer to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).